# How to implement an error wrapper for all existing Errors?

Tags: rust

I want to use my customised error type in all functions and I need to wrap the existing standard errors so that the `?` operator will succeed.

Here is what I am doing:

```
use std::{error::Error, fmt, fs};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyError {
    A,
    B,
}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, _f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Error for MyError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        ""
    }
}

trait NotMyError {}

impl<T: NotMyError + Error> From<T> for MyError {
    fn from(_: T) -> MyError {
        MyError::A
    }
}

fn test() -> Result<(), MyError> {
    fs::read_dir("test")?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::io::Error: NotMyError` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:30:5
   |
30 |     fs::read_dir("test")?;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `NotMyError` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<std::io::Error>` for `MyError`
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Comment: This seems to me like a bug. I can’t see where the unsized type `std::error::Error + Send + Sync` (which probably doesn’t implement `Error`, so that part is true) comes in—the `T` in the `From` implementation is `std::io::error::Error`. `std::io::error::Error` *contains* a boxed `Error + Send + Sync`, but that shouldn’t have any impact here.

Comment: Jon Reem helped explain it so it was clear to me: these negative impls are tied to the marker traits like `Send` and `Sync` and so it interacts poorly with trait objects; the type `std::error::Error`, for example, doesn’t implement `Send`, while `std::error::Error + Send` does. Using the negative implementations approach means that anything that contains a trait object that doesn’t have the `NotMyError` bound added (e.g. `std::error::Error + Send + Sync + NotMyError`) doesn’t implement `NotMyError`. So sorry, this approach I fed you earlier seems like it really won’t work.

Comment: e.g `impl error::Error for ParseClimateError {}`

Answer (score 24):

There's [an excellent post about it](https://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/). To get first-class support for your error you need to do two things:

- Implement [the `Error` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) for your type.
- Implement `std::convert::From` for error types you want to use seamlessly with the `?` operator (the [quick_error](https://lib.rs/crates/quick-error) crate helps automate this).